# AllureRestAssured , how to ignore logging headers

Tags: automated-testing, java, api-testing, rest-assured, allure

I am using rest-assured and allureRestAssured for testing api

```
given().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("key", key()).filter(new AllureRestAssured())
                .body(body.toString())
                .post(baseURI);
```

Problem here is its logged headers also , which contains auth key , which I dont want to be exposed in report generated , how can I ignore that .

Comment: How is this question different from your other question? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/47517/not-able-to-blacklist-header-value

Answer (score 2):

You can blacklist the headers you don't want to see in the report:

```
given().config(config().logConfig(logConfig().blacklistHeader("Accept"))). ..
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#blacklist-headers-from-logging).

Comment: Thanks for revert I already tried that , but no luck , its not working